# Trouble displaying images from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

My problem is thatmy code will only display one image from my database. I change the id to a different row, the name and everything else comes up fine but the image wont load. Even if I upload a new image this still happens? Please help!

```
<?php
session_start();
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
if(!empty($_SESSION['loggedin'])) { 


$id = $_GET['id'];
$conn = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=project", "root", 
"pass");
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM images where id = :id");
try {
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute();


while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
    if($row == false)
    {
        echo "Sorry nothing here!";
    }
    else {
        echo "$row[title]";
        echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $row['image'] ) . '" />';
        echo "$row[username]";
        echo "$row[description]";
        echo "$row[category]";
    }
}
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

What could be causing this? The images are stored as long blobs, their file types vary between jpg, jpeg, png and gif.
I have also tried the following which still works the same as above:

```
$image = $row['image'];
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($image) .'" />';
```

Comment: It would only display one image because you have a where clause in your query

Comment: Nooooo wayy, how should I put it if there shouldn't be a where?

Comment: Well, the assumption is that id is the PRIMARY KEY !?!?!

Comment: What? The id already is the primary key

Comment: Yes. So obviously it's only going to return one image. There is only one image!

Comment: I'm confused, I think there is some misunderstanding. There are 5 rows in the database, all 5 of which return data but no image, except row 1. This shows an image as well as, where as the other 4 do not.

Comment: What exactly you have in `$row['image']`?

Comment: A long blob, and if printed just jumbled text unless converted back to an image